# Versailles palace tickets. Musical Fountain Shows or Musical Gardens days or not if you are under 26 years old

Tags: france, budget, paris, versailles

It is not clear whether it is allowed to access Musical Fountain Shows or Musical Gardens or not, if you are under 26 years old.

Okay, first of all there is three types of tickets which you can take with free submission:

[image]

It's OK, if you are with this kind of ticker you can visit Palace of Versailies and the estate of Trianon, also you can visit Fontains and Musical Gardens, but only if there is not a shows, am I right?

There is two other types of free admission tickets:

[image]

Probably if you want to visit only palace with the gardens and fountains and if you want to visit Estate of Trianon but not the palace, am I right?

Based on this information:

[image]

If I got free submission but want to access fountains shows and musical gardens, I should pay price - 10 euro, but cannot find where to do it online, any ideas?

And the last one, If I got 20 euro passport instead of 27 euro passport:

[image]

And want to visit it in Tuesday, I cannot visit the gardens and the fountains, because there is a shows, right ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything is free if you are under 26 years old, also the Trianon.

There is just an exception: you can't visit the gardens when there are the musical fountains shows.

As it says on the ticket shop page:

> Attention, on days with Musical Fountains show or Musical Gardens, access to the Gardens is free only for children under 6. Tickets for the Musical Fountains Shows or the Musical Gardens can be bought online or at the entrance of the Gardens.

If you are under 26 you can get a reduced rate by buying tickets for the musical show and clicking "reduced rate" when you choose the number of tickets to buy.